# how to format string data like this '[1,fish#, 15,bird#, 4,horse#]' to '1,fish#15,bird#4,horse#'

Tags: flutter

```
how to format string data like this '[1,fish#, 15,bird#, 4,horse#]'
```

> to '1,fish#15,bird#4,horse#'

Comment: `String s =[4,'ahmed#',15,'up#'].join(',');`

Comment: it's not working well @pskink

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: Undefined name 'ahmed' because my code is ahmed not 'ahmed'. id and name have been concatenated into string "[4,ahmed#, 15,up#]"

Comment: please make the question that everyone can read and easy understand.

Comment: I have updated @tuan

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the model and map the list to the model

In your case your model class looks like this

```
class User  {
  final int user;
  final String tag;
  User({ required this.user, required this.tag, 
  
  });
}
```

List like this

```
 final List<User> userlist = [User(user: 4, tag: "ahmed#"),User(user: 15, tag: "up#"),];
```

when you need to get data use like this

```
userlist[0].tag,//0 is index
```

example

```
print(userlist[0].tag,) //this will print  **ahmed#**
```

Comment: then how do i get the format i want? @mrshakila

Comment: i just edited my answer you can check this now

Comment: the data in the list/model is filled using for, how to access it outside for? i need it outside for. that's why I use list.generate @mrshakila

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `join` and `replaceAll`.

```
export default function App() {
  const encode = (source: string[]): string => {
    return source.join(",").replaceAll("#,", "#");
  };

  const decode = (source: string): string[] => {
    return source
      .split(",")
      .reduce((p, n) => [...p, ...n.split("#")], new Array<string>())
      .map((e, i) => (i % 2 === 0 ? e : `${e}#`))
      .filter((e) => !!e);
  };

  let source = ["1", "fish#", "15", "bird#", "4", "horse#"];

  let sourceEncoded = encode(source);
  console.log("encode", sourceEncoded);
  // -> 1,fish#15,bird#4,horse# 

  let sourceDecoded = decode(sourceEncoded);
  console.log("decode", sourceDecoded);
  // -> ["1", "fish#", "15", "bird#", "4", "horse#"]

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code sanbox sample (console).

[image: Edit fervent-volhard-mwc585]

Comment: this works, but how can i loop the data, and only get the name @tuan

Comment: @AhmedSalavy im just updated codesanbox to added function to decode back to array from string.